# Rails 5 POST request adding extra parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My routes.rb file contains:

```
post 'products/:id/favorite', to: 'products#favorite'
delete 'products/:id/unfavorite', to: 'products#unfavorite'
get 'products/:id', to: 'products#show'
```

In my products controller, I have permitted `params.permit(:id)`

When I make a post request to `localhost:3000/products/1/favorite` with no body, I get the following in the rails console:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"1", "product"=>{}}
Unpermitted parameter: :product
```

Where did the extra `:product` param come from?

Comment: Could you please add the code of view template that you are posting from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your getting is wrapped parameters

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

You can turn it off by placing this in your controller

```
wrap_parameters false
```

This feature can be further customized in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb